# Do we all have to use the same BibTex label in order to compute correctly the number of citations?

Tags: bibtex

I'm writting an article for a journal. I'm using BibTex for the bibliography and I'm taking its entries from Google Scholar, for example:

```
@incollection{zhang2014instability,

title={Instability of Axial Flow Over a Plate Hinged at Its Leading Edge},

author={Zhang, Chao and Liu, Naitong and Huang, Lixi},

...
}
```

I would like to cite this entry as `\cite{Zhang}` in my Latex document. Can I just change the entry to `@incollection{Zhang}`, or is it necessary to keep it as `@incollection{zhang2014instability}` in order for the journal to compute one more citation for this article? In other words, does every article have to be defined with a unique label in all the world? If not, how is the number of citations of every article computed by the journals and Google?

Comment: The label only has to be unique in your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The citation key field must be terminated by a comma, not a curly brace. Thus, both

```
@incollection{zhang2014instability}
```

and

```
@incollection{Zhang}
```

will generate a BibTeX error. It has to be either

```
@incollection{zhang2014instability,
```

or

```
@incollection{Zhang,
```

The key point (pun intended) to keep in mind is that the citation key field must be *unique*.

Don't use TeX-special characters (`#$%_^&{}\`), spaces, double-quotes (`"`) or commas in the strings that form the citation keys, and don't employ non-ASCII characters (e.g., `äöüÄÖÜßàéè`, to mention but a few) either. Other than that, you're fairly free to choose how to write the citation key.